# Derivative by $a$ of the solution to $x’ = x^2 - x\cos t$, $x(0) = a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:
Find the derivative with respect to $a$ of the solution to the following IVP:
\begin{align}
x’ &= x^2 - x\cos t \\
x(0) &= a
\end{align}
at $a = 0$.

---

What I tried:

I'm not sure how to solve the quation explicitly (I am not sure I need to).

Yet, if I try to solve, I don't successeed.

Separation of variables is a problem because I have
$x\cos t$.

Linear of course not, Bernoulli doesn't work, substitioution I don't see how.

I would like a hint please.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by the derivative with respect to $a$ of an *initial value problem*?

Comment: Of course this is not *my* question, it is from homework. Yet maybe i didnt translate good enough. I think the question asks to find the solution function for the IVP and than to find the derivative with respect to $a$, $a$ Will be in the solution equation because $x(0) = a$ So the constant $c$ When we find the solution equation, will be a function of $a$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x’ = x^2 - x\cos t $$
Note that $x=0$ is a solution. This differential equation is [Bernoulli's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) 
$$\dfrac {x’}{x^2} = 1 - \dfrac {\cos t }x$$
$$-\left(\dfrac {1}{x}\right)' = 1 - \dfrac {\cos t }x$$
$$u' - u {\cos t }=-1$$
Where $u=\dfrac 1 x$. You should be able to solve this linear first order DE.

Comment: Thank you, i missed it, i tried it initially then stopped cuz i thought it is not working, thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome @Alon

Answer (score 0):

If $y=\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}$, then $$y'=2xy-y\cos t,~~~ y(0)=1$$ in addition to the ODE for $x$.

Now the reference solution $x$ is for the initial value $x(0)=0$, which gives the trivial solution $x(t)=0$. So it remains to solve
$$
y'=-y\cos t,~~~y(0)=1.
$$

Comment: Very nice solution, yet i dont fully understand how you concluded that you should take the trivial solution and not any other solution?

Comment: Because of the given expansion point $a=0$, which translates to $x(0)=a=0$.